# materialize dropdown menu doesn't work after jquery reload

Tags: jquery, select, materialize, dropdown

I'm using JQuery to load new content(with a Materialize select dropdown ) into a div when a user click the button. However a the new div is loaded, the select dropdown doesn't work. Here is how i'm doing it, any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#second-page").hide();
      $("#continue-button").click(function(){
        var $second_page_content=$("#second-page").html();
        $("#first-page").html($second_page_content);
        $("#second-page").trigger('contentChanged');
      });
     $("select").on('contentChanged', function(){
          $(this).material_select();
     });
  });
  </script>


<div class="row" id="first-page">
  <form>
  <div class = "row">
    <select id="animal">
      <option value = "bird">Bird</option>
      <option value = "cat">Cat</option>
      <option value = "Insect">Insect</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="continue-button">CONTINUE</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="row" id="second-page">
<form>
  <div class = "row">
    <select id="animal-type">
      <option value = "hen">Hen</option>
      <option value = "lion">Lion</option>
      <option value = "butterfly">Butterfly</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably must delegate the select event to its parent, or even to the document it self

Comment: Are those two div from different files? Otherwise, instead of moving html content, you can show/hide them preventing events to detach from their owners

Comment: @SubjectDelta, show/hide of divs doesn't work because after loading the content the previous status is restored, i.e. first-page shown, second-page hidden. It must be something with the .html() method that triggers document.ready again to set the elements to their initial state, or something

Comment: You can submit an hidden field wich will tell you wich form you must show... By the way, try those tips in my answer

Comment: @SubjectDelta It seems I have a workable solution for now that uses show/hide (and preventing page reloading with `event.preventDefault();`) It's not the most optimal but that can do for now. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the second page the select element also gets replaced hence the click handler isn't called anymore. Either you reattach the click handler after replacing or you use the selector parameter in the on() call.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write down what I suggested by comments...
This should do the trick:

```
$('#second-page').on('contentChanged', 'select', function() {
    $(this).material_select();
});
```

But I suggest you more something like

```
$("#continue-button").click(function() {
    $("#first-page").hide();
    $("#second-page").show();
});
```

**UPDATE**

I didn't read this `$("#second-page").trigger('contentChanged');` at the first read, you are actually triggering that event on `#second-page` and not on those select, so...

```
$('#second-page').on('contentChanged', function() {
    $(this).find('select').material_select();
});
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep your first idea, you must trigger that event on the select like this

```
$("#second-page").find('select').trigger('contentChanged');
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

You probably add code you didn't write in your question, because that should be a very simple task... Your forms are fake, there is no submit anywhere, no reload, just a mysterious `material_select`...

I tried to rewrote your stuff, it works as I suggested you.

Good luck

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#continue-button').click(function(){
    $('#first-page').hide();
    $('#second-page').show();
    $('#animal-type').material_select();
  });
});
```

```css
#second-page { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="first-page">
  <div class = "row">
    <select id="animal">
      <option value = "bird">Bird</option>
      <option value = "cat">Cat</option>
      <option value = "Insect">Insect</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="continue-button">
    CONTINUE
  </button>
</div>

<div class="row" id="second-page">
  <div class = "row">
    <select id="animal-type">
      <option value = "hen">Hen</option>
      <option value = "lion">Lion</option>
      <option value = "butterfly">Butterfly</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The principle of the question wasn't about beautiful forms, just how to make materialize selects work with dynamically loaded content.

Comment: Your solution is a hide/show one, calling the material_select again is not necessary(no new content is loaded when the button is clicked). `event.preventDefault` is necessary to prevent the page from reloading/re-showing first-page. working solution looks like this;
     ```$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#second-page').hide();
        $('#continue-button').click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#first-page').hide();
            $('#second-page').show();
        });
    });```